# Setting \topsep in breqn package

Tags: spacing, breqn

I'm using the [`breqn`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/breqn) package en `dmath` environment for multiline equations, and the normal `equation` environment for single line equations. However, the `\topsep` of `\abovedisplayskip` of this `dmath` environment is very large (especially in comparison to the normal equations), and I would like to make this smaller (and equal to the `equation` environment). However, I seem to not being able to change this; can anyone help me on this?

Comment: General comment about `breqn`: The package is far from finished so I wouldn't use it at all if I were you. Since Michael Downes passed away in 2003 and Morten Høgholm, after he took over the `breqn` development from Michael, left the (La)TeX community, no further development has been done on the package (as far as I know).

Comment: Any good alternative for breqn ?

Comment: I always use the 'standard' environments from [`amsmath`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/amsmath) or the extension package [`mathtools`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/mathtools).

Comment: It's not only that there is a lack of development effort (Michael did a _lot_ of work on the code), there's also the problem that it's not entirely clear that the automated approach can work in all cases.

Comment: @rubenbaetens Could you provide a MWE showing what you have tried?